# Silver Light Grid Select All Check Box

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, datagrid

I am new in Silverlight.
I have a datagrid where the first column contains a checkbox to let the user selects specific rows. I have added a checkbox in the datagrid column header to check or uncheck all the rows.
This is how I have added

```
<sdk:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                                <sdk:DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridColumnHeader">
                                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <CheckBox cal:Message.Attach="[Event Checked]=[Action SelectAllInPage()]; [Event Unchecked]=[Action UnSelectAllInPage()]" Margin="2,0,-13,0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DataContext.AllChecked, ElementName=LayoutRoot, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </sdk:DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            </sdk:DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                                               <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Household" Width="100" >
                                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="IsSelected" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5,5,0,0" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding HouseholdId}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0" FontSize="11" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The functionality is working fine, and as per expected, but it is showing two check boxes in first column.
When I removed the IsSelected checkbox,only one checkbox appears,but it is not allowing to select specific row.
What can be the cause of this problem and what should I do, I am assuming Binding IsSelected is causing this issue
I removed binding from DataGridCheckBoxColumn, its not showing any record in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the xaml you show in your question you declare two columns: one `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` and one `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a combination of `CheckBox` and `TextBlock` in its `CellTemplate`. Therefore you will see two CheckBoxes per row, the first one belongs to the DataGridCheckBoxColumn and the second one belongs to the DataGridTemplateColumn.
Either remove the CheckBoxColumn or remove the CheckBox from the TemplateColumn's CellTemplate.